# AppCompatEditText inside TextInputLayout paddingRight is not applicable for lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

Here is my XML works fine for 6.0 and above but doesn't work for lollipop (
Tested on Nexus 4 [5.1.1] and Xperia M2 [5.1.1] ).

`'@+id/inputText'` overlapping `'@+id/btn_choice_type'`.

**UPDATE**
Please see the screen shot. [image] Text is overlapping on other view, i think this is because of `TextInputLayout`. Entire view should be focused when user tap on `AppCompatEditText`, if i set the paddingRight to `TextInputLayout` then underline is not visible under 'Twitter' spinner, check below screen shot.[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:paddingRight="145dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:typeface="@string/font_regular" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/imageViewLine"
    android:layout_width="1.5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_choice_type"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_choice_type"
    android:background="#747474" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/btn_choice_type"
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewLine"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtError"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/err_msg_required"
        android:textColor="@color/profile_field_error_red"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <com.persource.android.ui.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/remove_social_account"
            android:textColor="#0072bc"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:typeface="@string/font_bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.persource.android.ui.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_private"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ch_public"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ch_public"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/lbl_show_before_connecting"
            android:textColor="#898989"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:typeface="@string/font_regular" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/ch_public"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditText` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` for all device support. And you have to give paddingRight to `Textinputlayout` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` if you use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`.

Comment: change width of `Textinputlayout`  `match_parent` to `wrap_content`. If its not work then show me your complete xml.